# Сколько способов представить число, как сумму трех разных чисел (строго O(n))

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

Нужно посчитать сколько есть способов представить число, как сумму трех разных чисел.
Например число 8 можно представить двумя способами: 1 + 2 + 5  и 1 + 3 + 4.
А число 6 одним: 1+2+3.
Решение должно быть O(n).
Мне пока удалось только посчитать количество способов, где два из трех слагаемых могут быть одинаковым. А вот как провести условие, чтоб все три были разные, не могу понять.

```
def count(n):
  counter = 0

  if n < 6: 
    return counter
  else:
    counter = (n - 1) * (n - 2) / 2

  return counter


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count(6)) #1 
    print(count(8)) # 2
    print(count(30)) # 61
    print(count(1337)) # 148296
```

Comment: Вообще-то 1+2+3==6...

Comment: да, пардон, исправлено

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А обязательно за O(n)? За O(1) можно?

```
n = int(input())

j = n//6
k = n % 6
if k == 0:
    j = j - 1
    k = 6

n = (3*j+k-3)*j
if k == 6: n = n+1

print(n)
```

Вроде бы так, если поверить вот [этому материалу](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath556/kmath556.htm)

Можно еще посмотреть на [эту](https://oeis.org/A034092) последовательность и [эту](https://oeis.org/A211540)

Нет, конечно, я могу вклеить сюда цикл и получить O(n)... :-)

Comment: Ну что вы, не стоит цикл вклеивать, раз так))

Comment: За `n` обычно берут объем данных. Для числа это количество цифр (битов). Умножение столбиком выполняется за O(n^2), есть способ [получше](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B), но он все равно не мгновенный и даже не линейный. Но это я так, занудствую :)

Comment: @extrn В данном случае все же n - это само число, а не количество бит в нем. Да и в рамках задачи, когда числа не произвольной огромной длины - умножение выполняется за одно и то же время...

Answer (score 0):

Легче посчитать количество плохих и вычесть из общего. Количество троек, где двое равны - можно посчитать за O(n)(можно и быстрее)(просто перебирать повторяющийся элемент). Количество троек, где равны может быть не больше 1(n либо делится на 3,либо нет). Количество троек всего равно C(n + 2, 2)